# Is there any reason behind having two ways of doing ng-init?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying out the angular js docs . I found this ng-init in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

There it is said that there are two ways of doing ng-init .

1. ng-init="{expression}"
2. class="ng-init:{expression}"

Is there any reason behind having two ways of doing same thing .

I tried out this is js fiddle as

```
1---->method 1 http://jsfiddle.net/3ghXP/

2---->method 2 http://jsfiddle.net/2Nyaf/1/
```

But I found one difference in the produced html .

In the html produced by method 1 there was class="ng-scope"

In the html produced by method 1 there was just a directive ng-scope

**But whats the difference between  the two ? 
where should I use each of them .**

Answer (score 2):

Every directive created in angularjs can be either applied at element, attribute, class or comment (EACM) level depending upon has it is configured. The `ng-init` directive has been configure to be usable as attribute or class and hence these two syntax. See [documentation for directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to understand these modes.

As to why they are required. I believe some of this is required for supporting older browser ([specially IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)) and maybe rest for convenience. I suggest you always stick to the attribute based `ng-init` syntax.